# Is there a way to call a function when a new day is selected on a calendar in ASP.Net/C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar, calendar-control

I want to write a function in my .cs file that is called when a new day is selected. I've searched Google for hours, and have come up with nothing.

Comment: could you please include the markup please?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an event handler for the Calendar object's `SelectionChanged` event:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.selectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx